# Treeview expand/collapse stops working after checking a checkbox

Tags: jquery, css, checkbox

I have some code for showing a tree made with a `<ul>` list, and I need 2 buttons for expanding and collapsing all of the tree items. This button works correctly
but I have problems when I click on a checkbox in my `<li>` tag. After that the 2 buttons do not work

If you check the result code and use the expand and collapse button you'll find my problem.

At first this button works very well, but when we clicked on a checkbox the buttons do not work at all.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#tree-collapse-all").click(function() {
    $(".tree input").removeAttr("checked");
  });

  $("#tree-expand-all").click(function() {
    $(".tree input").attr("checked", "checked");
  });
});
```

```css
ol,
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  list-style: none;
}

body {
  margin: 30px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#fontSizeWrapper {
  font-size: 16px;
}

#fontSize {
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 1em;
}


/* ————————————————————–
  Tree core styles
*/

.tree {
  margin: 1em;
}

.tree input {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.tree input~ul {
  display: none;
}

.tree input:checked~ul {
  display: block;
}


/* ————————————————————–
  Tree rows
*/

.tree li {
  line-height: 1.2;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 0 1em 1em;
}

.tree ul li {
  padding: 1em 0 0 1em;
}

.tree>li:last-child {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}


/* ————————————————————–
  Tree labels
*/

.tree_label {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
}

label.tree_label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

label.tree_label:hover {
  color: #666;
}


/* ————————————————————–
  Tree expanded icon
*/

label.tree_label:before {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 1em 0 -2em;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  content: '+';
  text-align: center;
  line-height: .9em;
}

:checked~label.tree_label:before {
  content: '–';
}


/* ————————————————————–
  Tree branches
*/

.tree li:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -.5em;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid rgb(7, 240, 112);
  content: "";
}

.tree_label:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -1.5em;
  display: block;
  height: 0.5em;
  width: 1em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(79, 7, 247);
  border-left: 1px solid rgb(240, 6, 6);
  border-radius: 0 0 0 .3em;
  content: '';
}

label.tree_label:after {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

:checked~label.tree_label:after {
  border-radius: 0 .3em 0 0;
  border-top: 1px solid rgb(79, 7, 247);
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(240, 6, 6);
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0.5em;
  height: auto;
}

.tree li:last-child:before {
  height: 1em;
  bottom: auto;
}

.tree>li:last-child:before {
  display: none;
}

.tree_custom {
  display: block;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><a href="#" id="tree-expand-all">Expand all</a> | <a href="#" id="tree-collapse-all">Collapse all</a></p>

<br /><br />
<div id="fontSizeWrapper">
  <label for="fontSize">Font size</label>
  <input type="range" value="1" id="fontSize" step="0.5" min="0.5" max="5" />
</div>
<ul class="tree">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="c1" />
    <label class="tree_label" for="c1">Level 0</label>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="c2" />
        <label for="c2" class="tree_label">Level 1</label>
        <ul>
          <li><span class="tree_label">Level 2</span></li>
          <li><span class="tree_label">Level 2</span></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="c3" />
        <label for="c3" class="tree_label">Looong level 1 <br />label text <br />with line-breaks</label>
        <ul>
          <li><span class="tree_label">Level 2</span></li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="c4" />
            <label for="c4" class="tree_label"><span class="tree_custom">Specified tree item view</span></label>
            <ul>
              <li><span class="tree_label">Level 3</span></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="c5" />
    <label class="tree_label" for="c5">Level 0</label>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="c6" />
        <label for="c6" class="tree_label">Level 1</label>
        <ul>
          <li><span class="tree_label">Level 2</span></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="c7" />
        <label for="c7" class="tree_label">Level 1</label>
        <ul>
          <li><span class="tree_label">Level 2</span></li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="c8" />
            <label for="c8" class="tree_label">Level 2</label>
            <ul>
              <li><span class="tree_label">Level 3</span></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you're using the `checked` attribute, which is not amended when a checkbox is interacted with by the user.

If you change your logic to work with the `checked` property of the element itself then the logic works correctly:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#tree-collapse-all").click(function() {
    $(".tree input").prop('checked', false);
  });

  $("#tree-expand-all").click(function() {
    $(".tree input").prop("checked", true);
  });
});
```

```css
ol,
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  list-style: none;
}

body {
  margin: 30px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#fontSizeWrapper {
  font-size: 16px;
}

#fontSize {
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 1em;
}


/* ————————————————————–
  Tree core styles
*/

.tree {
  margin: 1em;
}

.tree input {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.tree input~ul {
  display: none;
}

.tree input:checked~ul {
  display: block;
}


/* ————————————————————–
  Tree rows
*/

.tree li {
  line-height: 1.2;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 0 1em 1em;
}

.tree ul li {
  padding: 1em 0 0 1em;
}

.tree>li:last-child {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}


/* ————————————————————–
  Tree labels
*/

.tree_label {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
}

label.tree_label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

label.tree_label:hover {
  color: #666;
}


/* ————————————————————–
  Tree expanded icon
*/

label.tree_label:before {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 1em 0 -2em;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  content: '+';
  text-align: center;
  line-height: .9em;
}

:checked~label.tree_label:before {
  content: '–';
}


/* ————————————————————–
  Tree branches
*/

.tree li:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -.5em;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid rgb(7, 240, 112);
  content: "";
}

.tree_label:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -1.5em;
  display: block;
  height: 0.5em;
  width: 1em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(79, 7, 247);
  border-left: 1px solid rgb(240, 6, 6);
  border-radius: 0 0 0 .3em;
  content: '';
}

label.tree_label:after {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

:checked~label.tree_label:after {
  border-radius: 0 .3em 0 0;
  border-top: 1px solid rgb(79, 7, 247);
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(240, 6, 6);
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0.5em;
  height: auto;
}

.tree li:last-child:before {
  height: 1em;
  bottom: auto;
}

.tree>li:last-child:before {
  display: none;
}

.tree_custom {
  display: block;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><a href="#" id="tree-expand-all">Expand all</a> | <a href="#" id="tree-collapse-all">Collapse all</a></p>

<br /><br />
<div id="fontSizeWrapper">
  <label for="fontSize">Font size</label>
  <input type="range" value="1" id="fontSize" step="0.5" min="0.5" max="5" />
</div>
<ul class="tree">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="c1" />
    <label class="tree_label" for="c1">Level 0</label>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="c2" />
        <label for="c2" class="tree_label">Level 1</label>
        <ul>
          <li><span class="tree_label">Level 2</span></li>
          <li><span class="tree_label">Level 2</span></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="c3" />
        <label for="c3" class="tree_label">Looong level 1 <br />label text <br />with line-breaks</label>
        <ul>
          <li><span class="tree_label">Level 2</span></li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="c4" />
            <label for="c4" class="tree_label"><span class="tree_custom">Specified tree item view</span></label>
            <ul>
              <li><span class="tree_label">Level 3</span></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="c5" />
    <label class="tree_label" for="c5">Level 0</label>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="c6" />
        <label for="c6" class="tree_label">Level 1</label>
        <ul>
          <li><span class="tree_label">Level 2</span></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="c7" />
        <label for="c7" class="tree_label">Level 1</label>
        <ul>
          <li><span class="tree_label">Level 2</span></li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="c8" />
            <label for="c8" class="tree_label">Level 2</label>
            <ul>
              <li><span class="tree_label">Level 3</span></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I thanks you, you solve my problem very well,thank you so much